# Trouble parsing this String then returning it

Tags: java

I've been trying to parse this String format "X -> i" into String["X"] and String["i"]for a while, but haven't gotten it to work. Can anyone help me out?

I've tried:

```
public String[] parse(){

     String s = "X -> i";

        String[] tokens = s.split(" -> ");

        for (String t : tokens)
          return new String myarray[] {t, t};
        return myarray[];

}
```

It won't compile, but I can't figure out where the problem is logically.

Comment: Looks like all you want to do is return `tokens` itself.

Comment: That's all you need: `public String[] parse(){ return "X -> i".split(" -> "); }`

Comment: Returning tokens will create the array for me?

Answer (score 1):

```
public String[] parse(){
    String s = "X -> i";
    String[] tokens = s.split(" -> ");
    return tokens;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its much simpler than that

```
public String[] parse(){

    String s = "X -> i";

    String[] tokens = s.split(" -> ");

    return tokens;
}
```

Comment: You and @Greg have similar answers... but why did you use static while he did not?

Comment: Right .. That's an error. I was just testing this method and called it from a static main. Forgot to remove it. Edit coming

Answer (score 0):

Your compile error comes from the fact that you have two return statements.  You need only one.  once you fix this error (the one you asked about), the other answers will have to be taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

There are several 'logical' problems:

1. You have 2 return statements and no curly braces to separate the loop logic. (While not necessary it is the java convention, better for readability and reduces the chance for unseen bugs.

   ```
   parse() {
       return new String myarray[] {t, t};
       return myarray[];
   }
   ```

   delete the latter.
2. The use of the var name 'myarray' is redundant, delete them keeping the array [] declaration syntax.
3. You are using a method.

   Would be better to extract the variable from the method.

   ```
   public static String[] parse(String toParse) {
       return toParse.split(" -> ");
   }
   ```

From the mistakes it seems unknown in what format you actually want the tokens returned? Did you want the actual array of tokens as made by the split method? Or did you want two arrays. Here is some crazy code for the latter.

```
public String[][] parse(String toParse) {

    // String s = "X -> i";
    String[] tokens = toParse.split(" -> ");
    String[][] temp = new String[tokens.length][];

    int i = 0;
    for (String t : tokens) {
         temp[i++] = new String[] { t, t };
    }
    return temp;
}
```